# Unable to connect to AppleSMC from XCode

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have the following code to access the AppleSMC and control the fan speed. When I execute the swift file directly from command line (`swift ./my_file.swift`), then connection happens properly. If I transpose it to XCode and run it from there, then I get an error as indicated below. Anything I am forgetting ?

```
var mainport: mach_port_t = 0
var result = IOMainPort(kIOMainPortDefault, &mainport)
guard result == kIOReturnSuccess else { throw result }
let serviceDir = IOServiceMatching("AppleSMC")
let service = IOServiceGetMatchingService(mainport, serviceDir)
result = IOServiceOpen(service, mach_task_self_ , 0, &con).  ---> expression unexpectedly raised an error: -536870174
guard result == kIOReturnSuccess else { throw result }
```

Comment: I would check in "signing and capability" tab if there are no special authorization to grant the app, or any protection to deactivate (like to get out of the sandbox / hardened runtime / ...)

Comment: That was it, you're a king ! I deleted the sandbox from Signing and capabilities and it now works fine. Thanks !!

Comment: You are welcome ! But do not forget that without sandbox, no app store...